# How to execute function with arguments, inside another function with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to create simple app using Jquery, but I am stuck, i have two basic functions, first which holds the event, and second function, where i want to call first function, code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <button id="test" onclick="funct1(event,id)">clcik1</button>
     <button id="test2" onclick="mySecondFunction()">clcik2</button>

     <script>
      const funct1 = function myFunction(event,id) { 
        alert(event.target.id);
      };
      
      function mySecondFunction(){
        return funct1()
      } 


     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

problem is, first function holds (event and id), Accordingly when i call this function into my second function it throwing errors. I want, when i click second button executes first function... any solutions?

Comment: Since you're expecting an argument of `event` and an argument of `id` you need to pass this when calling it from your second function. You can kind of fake it if you want by using `funct1({ target: { id: "my id" } });`

Comment: You don't have to have "const funct1", and in the second function you can just call myFunction()

Comment: Well, what id do you expect to get alerted when you call the second function (when you click the second button)?

Comment: When i click second button, i want to receive first button id, in a word I want to execute first function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the arguments to mySecondFunction in onClick and in the js you should take it in mySecondFunction and pass it to funct1. Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <button id="test" onclick="funct1(event,id)">clcik1</button>
     <button id="test2" onclick="mySecondFunction(event,id)">clcik2</button>

     <script>
      const funct1 = function myFunction(event,id) { 
        alert(event.target.id);
      };
      
      function mySecondFunction(event,id){
        return funct1(event,id)
      } 


     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the arguments into your second function:

```
 const funct1 = function myFunction(event,id) { 
        alert(event.target.id);
      };
      
      function mySecondFunction(e, id){
        return funct1(e, id)
      }
```

and on the the button

```
 <button id="test2" onclick="mySecondFunction(event, id)">clcik2</button>
```

Something like this ?

Comment: No, sir, by the time when i click second button, i want to execute `myFunction` and receive alert(test) instead of (test2)